# iOS 14 UIPasteboard string returning nil from Today extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios14, today-extension, uipasteboard

Xcode 12.0, iOS 14, I am unable to access

`[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] string];`

from my Today widget extension, it returns (nil). I looked through the release notes and I did not see anything regarding this.

Comment: I can also confirm this issue. Today extension can read the pasteboard content correctly in simulator but returns nil when testing in device. Device and simulator both runs iOS 14.

Comment: Same, i guess the legit usage of this feature is too small and they removed it because will cause the clipboard banner to appear all the time.